# Why we use static method and static function in Singleton Pattern in C++?

Tags: c++

In Singleton Pattern we are using static method.Wanted to know the flow of static method and function calling in Singleton Pattern and why we use static in Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for creating a static function and static variable is that we don't want the compiler to make that allocation of memory when the program runs to be mutable. We don't want it to change.

The static method provides a CLASS public API which we can call to get the only copy of the value we want to work with.

```
// Example of a model object and a static get the only copy method.
Model::getInstance();
```